# How do I disable two clicks to close in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, mouse-click

--EDIT 20130213--

So, I've determined the cause for this.  Some applications within windows, Outlook being one of them, will not close a window if you click the x to close it while the window is not in focus.  So if I was working in another application maybe copying notes from an outlook message to another application, or some such, then went to close the outlook message without first gaining focus it gives me the "error" message first, at the same time setting focus to the message window.  With the second click focus is on the message and the X closes the window.  I guess this is a new feature?  I swear I've never experienced it before.

--END EDIT 20130213--

I just (within the past couple weeks) received a new Windows 10 Surface Book and one annoying "feature" that I'm experiencing is I have to click the "X" in the upper right hand corner twice to close most windows.

It happens in various applications (outlook, chrome, ssms, etc).

The first click makes the sound that windows makes when it stops you from doing something, like if you try to click a button but there's an open dialog.  Yet there's no open dialog.  Then I click the "X" a second time and the application closes.

Buttons and web links behave normally, it's just closing the application.

One thing I just noticed is this only happens the first time I attempt to close windows for an application after a reboot. Meaning, if I have two open outlook messages, I go through the two click process described above to close the first one, then the second (and beyond) messages close fine until I reboot when the two-click appears for that application.

It seems like it is some sort of windows setting, maybe to prevent accidental touches from closing windows in error but I've been unable to locate it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What you describe isn't a feature of Windows 10.  This behavior is either unique to your device, there is no feature, like what you describe in Windows 10 .  Something else is going on.

Comment: Does the same issue occur when you click on buttons or web links?

Comment: Does it behave the same way for all user accounts?  How about while booted in Safe Mode?

Comment: Does it work fine first time if using touch?

Comment: I am also running a surface book. This only happens with Office applications (outlook, word, visio, ...) and it only happens with mouse click. A close with touch does it in 1 tap.

Comment: I ended up getting rid of the surface book.  That plus too many other issues.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click the “Start” button and select “File Explorer“.
2. Select “View” > “Options” > “Change folder and search options“.
3. In the “Click items as follows” section, choose between “Single click to open an item” or “Double-click to open an item“.

[image]